# Java: send a file (XML) from webserver to another server

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, outputstream, fileinputstream

I have a simple question about **sending a file (XML file) from my webapp server to another server with Java (struts2 framework)**.

I **hope someone can give a look** to my code, because **it is impossible for me to check if the code will work** - the other server (the one that have to receive the file) is still not implemented. And I have to prepare my webapp server the most correct possible to send the file.

I have an XML file path, and the server address and the port its filled by the spring framework.

Looking at some examples in internet and also in some other questions in this awesome site, I have tried to write a simple code to send my file to the given address. **This is the code:**

```
private String server;
private Integer port;

// getters and settlers methods for server and port properties

public void sendXML(String fileName) throws Exception{
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);

        File file = new File(fileName);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        socket.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So, I will be very grateful if someone can give a look to my code and tell me if you think that it will not work. If you think that there is another better way to do it I also would be grateful to know it.

Thank you people, you are always really really helpful ;)

Regards,

Aleix

Comment: 'byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];' is a bad idea. Files may be larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, now I am trying to implement the sending trough Apache HttpClient4 library. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use HTTP rather than raw sockets. It will deal with timeouts, chunking, encoding, etc.

Have a look at the [commons http library](http://hc.apache.org/) (formerly known as http-client), it will save you writing your own code.

Comment: Thank you @artbristol, I will give a look to the http-client. I understand this is the best way for me to send the XML file. Regards:)

Comment: Oh, first I though you were talking about the commons-httpclient3 library, but I have just realise that this is obsolete. I understand that it is better if I use the Apache HttpClient4 library, true?

Comment: Hey artbristol, one last question, if after sending the XML file, I want to wait and get an answer (only text with a result) from the same server where I have sent the XML, how you recommend me to implement it? Again, thank you very much in advance for your help;)

Comment: You can return anything you want in the response body to a POST/PUT request (which I you will use for sending the file). Or, return a Location header which points to the URL of the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have look how to do it trough HTTP with the Apache HttpClient4 and HttpCore4 libraries and I have wrote this code, you think it would work properly? Thank you very much!

```
private String server;
//private Integer port;

// getter and settler methods for server property

public void sendXML(String fileName) throws Exception{
    try{
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(file, "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(server);
        method.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```